# EEG amplifier circuit low and high pass filters. Oscillations, noise, etc

Tags: amplifier, filter, low-pass, biopotential, oscillation

I designed a EEG amplifier circuit for for EEG signal amplification and filtering.

Because I never had any experience in filters, It would be highly appreciated if someone could check my design.

In general circuit looks like this: AD620->Driven Leg->DC-restoration(offset correction)->two passive filters(low and high pass) before amplification->regulated amplifier, gain 1..25->2nd order active high-pass, gain 1.5->4th order active low-pass, gain 30->passive high pass->to ADC

50 hgz hum cancellation done with Driven Leg. 
Offset correction schematic, DLR block and AD620 are not shown.

The first my concern is oscillation.

I am going to use TL084CN op-amps. And their oscillation can be a problem.

The second my concern is filter design. I used online tools for filters design:

http://www.analog.com/designtools/en/filterwizard
http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPttool.php

According to okawa-densh tool some of the filters will oscillate. For e.g. Oscillation frequency for 1-st stage of low-pass second order filter:

f = 71 [Hz]

For High-pass filter:

f=0.16 [Hz]

Is it normal?

I simulated circuit in LTspice, images below. Graph is frequency response. Lines on graph marked with dots on the schematic.
[image: circuit]
[image: Frequency response]

Thank you.

Comment: TL084s are terrible op amps for a 3V split supply.

Comment: For supply I am going to use 6x1.2 batteries. And split it with TL084. Like this:
https://db4c15cb-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/chipstein/home-page/eeg-with-an-arduino/assembling-the-arduino-eeg-circult/Arduino%20PreampNG.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7cqgDMMD_y2kBVy2fRbJ5I2ngGQOSkT5muhYGpgCy0Rmr49HkeovQTn0_qTiU6C0nQPjOTx_a5Zg0CI_8pKXwXXQBCD2XbcwRdUMRpjPrs7FVCSg4gaH_rNw6M7EaamlVDczJyjvaAs-RUZdUOh1gH-MYYScORAnh7z25tWWB7RC5n61-c-gZGy53J7jPzbSY1LotSZot-uSCy571AXlLyLtANsCItv6eTJmvBN7jCtfJJizQQmUEiHf55dRjsKODQt1bcU4bD-XhluOhn0YrxxW_hcPaHoLowL9zclOvSyzFLz6YmFcjnQCF2ioJPY0lJF9DhT-&attredirects=0

Comment: Is OP07 good choice?
What can you recommend instead TL084? Thak you.

Comment: Both suck equally for low voltage power rails. I would start with a LMP7704. It's not as fast, but has rail-to-rail I/O.

Comment: You shouldn't necessarily consider DRL to be the same as hum cancellation.

Comment: The AD620 isn't great for small rails, either.  Try an AD623

Comment: In my town it is hard to find something like LMP7704 at an affordable price and within a reasonable delivery time. So, I will start with ancient and cheap LM324. Switching to something better shouldn't be so hard. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Oscillation frequency" is a term that describes the frequency where the input-output phase relationship is exactly zero degrees i.e. if this filter were part of a circuit used as an oscillator it would oscillate at this frequency. Sometimes oscillation frequency is quoted at 180 degrees phase shift (inverting filter configurations)

It doesn't mean the circuit on its own will oscillate. Look at the results of an RLC low pass filter: -

[image]

Clearly this circuit doesn't oscillate but, all the same, it has an oscillation frequency.